# Custom directives within scss files? Perhaps for a new pseudo class?

Tags: sass, pseudo-class

**Is it be possible to use some sort of @directive creation syntax, similar to creating @mixins?  Secondly, is it possible to create a SASS-only pseudo class?**

I'd like to declare my own SASS directive,although I'd prefer not to have to force my teammates to install an extra ruby gem to use it so I'd want to store it in a scss partial.    I do understand that they are orders of levels in complexity, so perhaps it just isn't possible.

In addition to perhaps creating a new scss-only pseudo class (such as :parent, :clicked, :unchecked, etc) I'd be interested in a custom-made directive that assists with using checkboxes to direct css animations ("css checkbox hack").  Here is my scss pseudocode to generalize what I'm trying to do:

```
//  this code monitors when a checkbox (#someinput) is checked,
//  then applies style to div #target div.  Basically an 'onClick' event in scss.
body {
  #wrapper {
    #targetdiv {
      @spotcheck(#someinput) {                 #
        color: red; border: 2px solid blue;    # <-- move this ...
      }                                        #

      color: blue; border: 0;
      #someinput {
        width: 20px; height: 20px;
      }
    }
  }
}

// ... the above scss should be converted to this pre-compiled state, also scss
body {
  #someinput:checked ~ #targetdiv {           #
    color: red; border: 2px solid blue;       # <-- ..to here. it needs to be 
  }                                           #       above the #targetdiv

  #wrapper {
    #targetdiv {
      color: blue; border: 0;
      #someinput {
        width: 20px; height: 20px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your selectors only as specific as they absolutely need to be and no more.  A mixin would only be more verbose with no real benefit.

```
#targetdiv {
    color: blue; border: 0;

    #someinput:checked ~ & {
        color: red; border: 2px solid blue;
    }
}

#someinput {
    width: 20px; height: 20px;
}
```

Output:

```
#targetdiv {
  color: blue;
  border: 0;
}
#someinput:checked ~ #targetdiv {
  color: red;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

#someinput {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Alternately, this would give the same result with the ability to overqualify as much as you want:

```
#targetdiv {
    color: blue; border: 0;
}

#someinput {
    width: 20px; height: 20px;

    ~ #targetdiv {
        color: red; border: 2px solid blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that actual Sass syntax, with the '&' referring to the parent element?:  #someinput:checked ~ &

Comment: Yes, plain Sass (scss).

Comment: I didn't know that existed, thanks.  By the way, do you have thoughts on the main question posed, which concerns a way to create a '@directive' or pseudo class, perhaps in an imported scss file (instead of ruby)?

Comment: My opinion doesn't matter a whole lot, but the maintainers of Sass are hesitant to add new directives unless there are solid use cases for them.  If I were to guess, I would say that this probably would not be one of those cases.

Comment: I was surprised to see the & at the end of the line.  The reason why is because it doesn't work.  It needs to appear at the start, unfortuantely.  It would be great if it did, though.

Comment: Can you provide an example where this doesn't work?  I compiled both examples via Sass.  There *are* some instances where & is allowed at the end, but most people don't understand why.

Comment: Well it seems to be an oversight of the parser on the Sass devs part (rather than a feature), because the & at the end (or perhaps anywhere but the start) pulls in the root (html body ...).  So in your example, I see this: #someinput:checked ~ html body #targetdiv {

Comment: You're overqualifying.  When would you have a #targetdiv *outside* of html/body elements?  "Doesn't work" is pretty vague: there's a world of difference between "doesn't give the desired output" and "doesn't compile".

Comment: Well, I didn't want to divert the discussion from my main topic, concerning Sass directives/mixins.  I appreciate your advice here.  To answer your question, it does compile, but it doesn't give the desired output.  The comments on this thread go into more if you are curious as to what I mean:  http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand